# Spring - Server Sent Event - Can a single SseEmitter share multiple sessions?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I have this case where I have companies, and companies can have multiple users.
The **sseemitter** will only be sent on events that happen in the company, for example :
*the company name changed event.*
In that case, I would like to send a message via this event emitter to **all open sessions of this company**.
My question is do I need to create a sseemitter for each user, or should I just create a single emitter for the company and share it with all the users (of course after giving it to them via an endpoint).

Comment: Yes, multiple client browsers can subscribe to the same stream and they ail all receive each message.